# Defining hierarchy using XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I want to define a hierarchy as such:

```
Category 1
  SubCategory 1.1
  SubCategory 1.2
Category 2
  SubCategory 2.1
```

And I would like to do it using Android's XML files (the ones that go inside the "values" folder) and not using code.

In a "regular" XML file I would do something like:

```
<category>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Category 1</title>
</category>

<category>
  <id>11</id>
  <title>Category 1.1</title>
  <parent_id>1</parent_id>
</category>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should try putting your file in a res/xml/ folder instead of res/values/ and then you can access it like normal XML at runtime with Resources.getXML().

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes